# keras Loss history not reporting all epoch's

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

So I am using a generator to do a LSTM and after running the model I want to create a plot of the loss of the training data using history. When I do this I am under the impression it should be reporting the loss for each epoch but the length of the loss array is way shorter than the number of epochs I was wondering if this has something to do with the batch size in the generator?
Here is my code,

```
n_steps=1
n_features=1
batches=10

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add( tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))#maybe make y the next 14 timesteps instead of one
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

steps=len(train_temp)/batches

history=model.fit_generator(e,steps_per_epoch=steps, epochs=100, verbose=1)
history.history['loss']
```

This then comes out to 10 numbers

Comment: how many values when you change the epochs to 1

Comment: what does this `train_temp` variable represent?

Comment: when I change epochs to 1 it is just one value. train_temp represents the training set not split into xtrain or ytrain yet. e is the generator that pulls out batches of data